# Refresh Gradle Project in Eclipse rewrites project settings

Tags: eclipse, gradle, refresh

In Eclipse when I right click on a Gradle project and select Gradle -> Refresh Gradle Project, it changes the project JDK to JRE System Library (unbound) and Java compliance to 1.4 or lower. The same happens when I run tasks *gradle cleanEclipse eclipse*.

Any idea how to prevent that? Most likely how to set the project in the `eclipse {...}` block? Thanks...

Comment: What `targetCompatibility` did you set in `build.gralde`?

Comment: `targetCompatibility = 10`

Comment: Under `Java > Installed JREs > Execution Environments`, what JRE is selected for `JavaSE-10`?

Comment: There's no `JavaSE-10`. There's only `jdk-10.0.1`.

Comment: Under `Execution Environments` (on the left side) you can't have a JRE version. If there is no EE for JavaSE-10 no wonder it reverts to 1.4. What Eclipse version are you using?

Comment: It was Oxygen. I just switched to 2018-09.

Comment: Yeah, Oxygen didn't support 10, so that's why you got the "unbound" error.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out! I had to specify the JVM path in eclipse.ini. After adding this:

```
-vm
PATH_TO_THE_JDK\bin\javaw.exe
```

above the `-vmargs` option it's resolved.

The compliance level stays on 10. The JDK keeps switching to JavaSE-10, but it's no more *unbound* and the syntax checker also stopped screaming about missing libraries.

Comment: It is also possible to pass this value as a command parameter. For example:

`C:\Eclipse\eclipse-jee-2022-03-R\eclipse.exe -vm C:\jdk-11.0.15+10\bin`